# Convert PowerShell object to JSON, in particular IP address

Tags: json, powershell, networking, ipv4

Need to get some information about network interfaces:

```
> Get-NetIPConfiguration | select IPv4Address, InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDes    cription | ConvertTo-Json
```

Respond

```
[
    {
        "IPv4Address":  [
                            "MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = \";C?8;@B8CC8;??55;:55;55;\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemCr
eationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"\")"
                        ],
        "InterfaceAlias":  "wifi",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter"
    },
    {
        "IPv4Address":  [
                            "MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = \";@C8???8;??8??B55;@55;55;\", CreationClassName = \"\", SystemC
reationClassName = \"\", SystemName = \"\")"
                        ],
        "InterfaceAlias":  "Ethernet",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"
    }
]
```

This look like strange enough. I expect something like:

```
[
    {
        "IPv4Address": "12.3.3.4",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "wifi",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter"
        "NetAdapter.Status" : "connected"
    },
    {
        "IPv4Address":  "192.168.0.1",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "Ethernet",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"
        "NetAdapter.Status" : "connected"
    }
]
```

Also need to get interface status connected or disconnected, it is stored in `NetAdapter.Status`.
Please help. It shold be better to write it all in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in one line...

```
$n = Get-NetIPConfiguration | select InterfaceIndex, IPv4Address, InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription, NetAdapter
ForEach( $a in $n ){
    $a.Ipv4Address =  $a.Ipv4Address.IpAddress
    $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Status -value $a.NetAdapter.Status
    $a.PSObject.Properties.Remove('NetAdapter')
}

$n
$n | ConvertTo-Json
```

Result:

```
InterfaceIndex       : 10
IPv4Address          : 192.168.99.135
InterfaceAlias       : wifi
InterfaceDescription : Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter
Status               : Up

InterfaceIndex       : 16
IPv4Address          : 169.254.153.248
InterfaceAlias       : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Status               : Disconnected

[
    {
        "InterfaceIndex":  10,
        "IPv4Address":  "192.168.99.135",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "wifi",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter",
        "Status":  "Up"
    },
    {
        "InterfaceIndex":  16,
        "IPv4Address":  "169.254.153.248",
        "InterfaceAlias":  "Ethernet",
        "InterfaceDescription":  "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller",
        "Status":  "Disconnected"
    }
]
```

**I am sure, there is more short and may be optimal way**

Answer (score 3):

You need to traverse objects deeper:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | select IPv4Address, InterfaceAlias, InterfaceDescription | 
  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
```

By default powershell goes only 3 levels deep

Comment: thank you, this seems to be close but not what i looking for.